# How to parse binary data from socket in python?

Tags: python, parsing, sockets, modem

I'm currently working on a project where I need to communicate to a microhard cellular modem IPn3G. I have the modem set up to send messages to my computer through TCP and I can pick up the message in a socket.

The message looks like this though:

```
���������DKReadyCANRogersWirelessInc. Home354626030393530302720391029547
```

Now, I can recognize a few of these fields like the Status or the Carrierinfo as well as the imei and imsi in the end.

My problem is, how do I parse the funny looking things? I have tried struct, but it didn't seem to help me out very much.

In the documentation of the modem I only found this:

Modem_event message structure:

- fixed header (fixed size 20 bytes)
- Modem ID (uint64_t (8 bytes))
- Message type mask (uint8_t(1 byte))
- reserved
- packet length (uint16_t(2 bytes))
  Note: packet length = length of fixed header + length of message payload.

Carrier info:

- Content length 2 BYTES (UINT16_T)
- RSSI 1 BYTE (UINT8_T)
- RF Band 2 BYTES (UINT16_T)
- Service type STRING (1-30 Bytes)
- Channel number STRING (1-30 Bytes)
- SIM card number STRING (1-30 Bytes)
- Phone number STRING (1-30 Bytes)

To me it seems like the message doesn't even line up with what it's supposed to be. I would be very glad if anyone had advice on how to tackle this problem.

Thank you

Comment: What the message "looks like" e.g. when printed to your console is not very useful. In particular any NUL (`'\x00'`) bytes are unlikely to show up. Instead of `print message` do `print repr(message)`

Comment: Does the documentation show how long "reserved" is? What do you mean by "or" in "I can recognize a few of these fields like the Status or the Carrierinfo"? What is "Status"? What should be in "fixed header"?

Comment: @JohnMachin: The new output with repr(message) is "\xb7\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Z\x00D\x00\xf3\x00\x00Ready\x00CANRogersWirelessInc.\x00Home\x00354626030393530\x00302720391029547\x00".

Comment: Also the documentation doesn't say how long reserved is or what is in the fixed header. I recognize a few fields like Status=Ready, Carrier=CANRogersWirelessInc., Home=Home, the IMEI=354626030393530 and the IMSI=302720391029547. But they actually shouldn't be in the output so I don't know if this is part of the header.

Comment: The message you show has only 25 bytes before the variable-length strings that start with "Ready". As you say, it doesn't match up with either of the two snippets of documentation. You have a documentation problem, and we can't help you with that. Surely this device must be using some international standard protocol to communicate ...

Comment: Alright, that's what I was thinking too. I'm hoping to get an answer from the microhard support that can help me figure out the message. Well, thank you anyways for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Python has great [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module, which allows you to pack and unpack binary data.

I see, that you've already tried to use it. I don't have a documentation, for your device (go and check it!), but I can suppose, that strings are null-terminated (they don't have their size given anywhere before).

Get the size of the string part of the message (from size of the other fields and packet length) and read all strings into one Python string using `<number>s` and split them finding the null characters.